# Swift index of array of Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I have two arrays:

```
var array = Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>()

var deletes = Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>()
```

I am appending deletes into array based off index:

```
for item in indexPaths {
            deletes.append(self.array[item.item])
        }
```

Else where in my code, I am now trying to get the index of self.array of the item in delete:

```
for item in deletes {
let i = self.array.index(of: item)!
                self.array.remove(at: i)
}
```

However on I am getting this error on let i

> Cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of: [String :
>   Any])'

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the index of array of dictionary?

Comment: [index(of:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689674-index) works on array where the elements conforms to the equatable protocol. you are using `Any` therefore it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use `.index(of`  on Dictionary of Any value

but use  `.index(Where`

```
 for item in deletes {
        let i = array.index { (dic) -> Bool in
              // return item[""] == dic[""] condition
        }
        if i != nil {
            self.array.remove(at: i)

        }

    }
```

Comment: I tried this `array.index { (dic) -> Bool in
            
            return true
            
        }`

Comment: you have to use `item`

Comment: However I don't understand how its gettting the index from deletes, also I get this warning...Result of call to 'index(where:)' is unused

Comment: Still getting Result of call to 'index(where:)' is unused

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in deletes {
    if let i = self.array.index(of: item) {
        self.array.remove(at: i)
    } else {
        // item is not member of array. 
    }

 }
```

Comment: Same error `Cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of: [String : Any])'`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the problem is the declaration of your **deletes** array.
The dictionaries within that array have to have a key of type String and a value of Any.
But Any is not hashable which is needed by `index(of:)` to work. So if you can guarantee that your Value is always hashable you should change your declaration and you can use the `index(of:)` method.

Change to

```
var deletes = Array<Dictionary<String, AnyHashable>>()
```

and this will work

```
for item in deletes {
let i = self.array.index(of: item)!
                self.array.remove(at: i)
}
```